# Using button.enabled outside the Button_Click sub

Tags: vb.net

I am just starting out with Visual basic .Net. I am designing an application where each button should disable itself after a registering a single click on it.

I am trying to add an additional sub, which when called, disables all of the buttons. (Disable_all())

```
Public Sub disable_all()
MsgBox("Testing disable_all")
Button_eight.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

One of the subs is calling it from the main module.

```
    Private Sub disable()
    Dim variab As Form1 = New Form1
    variab.disable_all()
    End Sub
```

The disable_all() sub however does not disable Button_eight when called. I placed a message box to check if the sub (disable_all) is getting executed, which it is. I get a message box having the text "Testing disable all" but the Button_eight is not disabled for some weird reason.

I'd really appreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: You are creating a new Form1 and disabling the button on that form not the visible form1

Comment: If I don't add the line Dim variab As Form1 = New Form1, it throws a warning and then a Nullreference exception error when that code is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, just do `Form1.disable_all()`.

That is, instead of `variab.disable_all()`, call: `form1.disable_all()` from the main module. Because as mentioned in the comments, `new form1` creates a new instance of `Form1`.

You can also create a variable that point to the form `dim var = form1` or `dim variab as form = form1`, but since you can access `form1` directly from your module, it is unnecessary.